# Authentication redirect route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

can you help me how to create if `isadmin` is `true` it will be redirected to admin page, else home page.

> AuthController

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
       if(!auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return redirect()->back();
       }
       return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

the main reason's maybe because this

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

when tried change to ('admin') it successfully redirecting.

when i tried to add

```
protected function authenticated(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $user)
    {
        if( $user->isadmin){
           return redirect('admin');
        }
        return redirect('home');
    }
```

it didnt works too

Comment: Its possible using middleware and You can find the answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/user-admin-authentication?page=0#reply=68074

Comment: still didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a middleware and using it to protect the route

Example, you can create an Admin middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
```

In App\Http\Middleware\Admin.php

```
use Auth;
use Session;
use Closure;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if user has permission to access route
        if(!Auth::user()->admin) {
            Session::flash('info', 'You do not have permission to perform this operation!');

            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Then in the protected route(assuming only your admin can view all posts in this route),

```
Route::post('admin/post/index', 'PostController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

Or in the controller

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('auth');
 }
```

Use `except` to exclude routes or `only` to include methods.

In the kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     ...
     'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
];
```

Comment: did we need to add column admin to user databases?

Comment: yes, there should be an admin column in the database

Comment: what should i choose for the type? it is boolean? or something else

Comment: something like this in your create_users_table migration `$table->boolean('admin')->default(0);`

Comment: any one you prefer to use. Just ensure it matches in the your code

Comment: it must match with this right `if(!Auth::user()->admin) {`

Comment: great! nice to hear

Comment: there's problem, even after i set Admin to true, i can't acces my admin routes

Comment: ahhh, my bad. it's just a typo from my code. it work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this situation is using middleware as @sssurii told you

I have a roles table which states normal users and admin user, and additionally I have a middleware such the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(!$user->role->title==='Admin'){
            return route('user');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in kernel class, I've added that middleware in routes

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ....
        'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
    ];
```

Now you need to protect your admin routes, it is solver by

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin'], 
'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
            Route::get('/home', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
    .....
    }
```

Here you have a way to filter requests to admin routes, and let get in only users that belongs to group/role Admin.
After that if you want an automatic redirect at login, you should modify redirectPath function in Auth controller (usually at `app/http/controllers/auth/AuthController.php`)

```
public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->role->title === 'Admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
    }
```